# flow-type for dynamic dependencies of possible values of 'A' attribute (Array<prop>) on values 'B' ([prop: string]: any)

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I have next type definition:

```
type $Schema = {
  type?: 'object' | 'string' | 'number' | 'array',
  properties?: { [key: string]: $Schema },
  additionalProperties?: boolean,
  range?: [number, number],
  required?: Array<string>
}
```

I want to change it for preventing putting keys to `required` which not yet defined in `properties`.
In the next example, using `xx` should be marked as an error, because it defined in 'properties':

```
{  
  required: ['id', 'xx'],
  properties: { id: { type: 'string' } }
}
```

Harder example:

```
const testSchema = {
  properties: {
    foo: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        bar: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      },
      required: ['buz']
    }
  },
  required: ['foo']
}
```

I want to make it harder to make mistakes during using JSON-Schema in flow compatible IDEs/Editors.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use generic + $Keys<...>, like this:

```
type $Schema<T: {[key: string]: $Schema<*>}> = {
  type?: 'object' | 'string' | 'number' | 'array',
  properties?: T,
  additionalProperties?: boolean,
  range?: [number, number],
  required?: Array<$Keys<T>>
}
```

and check schema:

```
const testSchema: $Schema<*> = {
  properties: {
    foo: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        bar: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      },
      required: ['buz']
    }
  },
  required: ['foo']
}
```

Repl: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AEgMoDGAFlgLYCGAPACoBcoA3gNoDWWaDAzigE4CWAOwDmAXQYES5agCoAfAF85oALxNEoUOmwB+BgHJYAIwBWWQin2gAPqH08BIq7f2CArmSNZezuxV68FGj6ADQaoBi8sNi8KPxYXHqgNGGaFAAm6fxxsIIU0AAKUTFxCUlGsLDQWBSCqaCBIlhJzO6e3iGgbV68ovW8WACObvwD6UkAggFBVLgA0hxctHJyiAqgyIS5PFoJKESklBIH0lTyquqakdHepVwMjOGakJUPT5pamFgGxmYWoe8rsVbvF7pcPhCjP43hDYZ9sAYHEJhPpAR8FGiFPUIQNhqMsOkGMx9EY3AAvfSid4YzRY8K4kZjIn6F6wSlrIA