# Type the scheme using flowtype

Tags: node.js, mongoose, flowtype

I create a database using the mongoose js. I don't know how to type it.
Help type the scheme using flowtype.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  loginName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 100,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 8,
    maxlength: 1024,
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem ?

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461813/flow-type-for-dynamic-dependencies-of-possible-values-of-a-attribute-arraypr -  you can start with that